# JQuery DataTable data not available even data is received from server

Tags: datatables

I want to draw a table to show users data from my server. 
First I am using Ajex to get the users data:

```
var usersList = {};
usersList.users = ["Afthieleanmah", "Hadulmahsanran","tabletest1"];
var dataSet1=[];
var i;

$.ajax({
    url:  '../users',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(usersList),
    success:function(response, text){
        if(response.users !== undefined){
            dataSet1 = response.users;
        } 
    }
});
```

I can successfully get the users data and save the data in dataSet1 as a JSON array contains Objects. Its format is like this:

```
   [
       { 
          username: "Tiger Nixon",
          job_title: "System Architect",
          city: "Edinburgh",
          extn: "5421"
       },
       { 
          username: "Tiger Nixon2",
          job_title: "System Architect",
          city: "Edinburgh",
          extn: "5421"
       }
   ]
```

Then I create a table and pass in configuration:

```
// table confirgurations
var tableConfig={
    pageLength: 5,
    bLengthChange: false,
    columns:[
        {data: "username", title: "Name"},
        {data: "job_title", title: "Position"},
        {data: "city", title: "City"}
    ],
    data:dataSet1
};

// create table 
var userTable=$('#table-id').DataTable(tableConfig);
```

I am sure that I can get users data from API "/users" and save it into dataSet1. But everytime I load the page containing the table, the table always shows "No data available in table". I set a breakpoint on this line :

```
 var tableConfig={
```

and let it continue to run. The weird things happen. The Table shows the data.............. No idea why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should initialize your table **after** you receive response from the server in the `success` function. Also use [`destroy`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/destroy) in case you're performin your Ajax request multiple times.

For example:

```js
$.ajax({
    // ... skipped ...
    success:function(response, text){
        if(response.users !== undefined){
            dataSet1 = response.users;
        }

        // table confirgurations
        var tableConfig={
           // ... skippped ...
           destroy: true
        };

        // ... skippped ...

        var userTable=$('#table-id').DataTable(tableConfig);
    }
});
```

However ideally you should let jQuery DataTables do the Ajax request using [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option.

Comment: thanks. I used https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/26282/posting-json-with-built-in-ajax-functionality to post data to my API and the DataTable can successfully get data back and render the table.